# Where are my car liveries saved?

Tags: pc, grid-2

I'd like to know where the liveries for my cars are saved so that I can share them with my friends, and download new ones.

On the `PC` `Steam` version, does anyone know where they are saved?

Comment: Can the downvoter please post a comment about why they downvoted so that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can, it appears that all game save data is stored in this location;

`<Steam Install Folder>\userdata\<Profile ID>\44350\`

I have three files in this location, two *.lkr files, one of which is much larger than the other two files, so I assuming this is the actual save file. Of the remaining files, I would assume that one of these will likely be for profile information.

I suspect that the livery save data is stored in the large file along with the other save data in this folder.

Comment: Bah, this isn't the <strike>droids</strike> news I was hoping for.